# how to count occurrences of specific string in previous x rows

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a list of activities and the approximate timestamp they occur in. I would like to count the occurences of a string in the previous 'x' rows (walking or running etc.) and add it to the dataframe. Pandas DataFrame does not support rolling (for non-numeric data) and I'm not sure if I can use shift to check like the previous 30, 50 or even 70 rows of data. I haven't made any concrete progress yet as I have been looking for similar questions/solutions on the site.

```
    timestamp   event
0   2021-12-18 18:20:25+08:00   running
1   2021-12-18 18:20:27+08:00   running
2   2021-12-18 18:20:29+08:00   walking
3   2021-12-18 18:20:31+08:00   walking
4   2021-12-18 18:20:33+08:00   walking
5   2021-12-18 18:20:35+08:00   walking
6   2021-12-18 18:20:37+08:00   walking
7   2021-12-18 18:20:39+08:00   walking
8   2021-12-18 18:20:41+08:00   stationary
9   2021-12-18 18:20:43+08:00   stationary
10  2021-12-18 18:20:45+08:00   stationary
11  2021-12-18 18:20:47+08:00   stationary

df.loc[:, 'Count previous K'] = 0  # new column to count previous row activities
```

expected output:

```
    timestamp   event   Count previous K
0   2021-12-18 18:20:25+08:00   running 0
1   2021-12-18 18:20:27+08:00   running 0
2   2021-12-18 18:20:29+08:00   walking 1
3   2021-12-18 18:20:31+08:00   walking 2
4   2021-12-18 18:20:33+08:00   walking 3
5   2021-12-18 18:20:35+08:00   walking 4
6   2021-12-18 18:20:37+08:00   walking 5
7   2021-12-18 18:20:39+08:00   walking 6
8   2021-12-18 18:20:41+08:00   stationary  6
9   2021-12-18 18:20:43+08:00   stationary  6
10  2021-12-18 18:20:45+08:00   stationary  6
11  2021-12-18 18:20:47+08:00   stationary  6
12  2021-12-18 18:20:49+08:00   stationary  5
```

for a window size of 10 (including current index/row) counting occurences of walking.

Comment: Please add your expected output as a dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a boolean to see when a particular event is occurring, then perform a rolling sum on the boolean series. As @mozway pointed out, the argument `min_periods=1` will avoid `NaN` appearing at the beginning of the resulting DataFrame:

```
df['walking_count'] = (df['event'] == 'walking').rolling(5, min_periods=1).sum()
```

This sets a new column `'walking_count'` to the following series:

```
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     1.0
3     2.0
4     3.0
5     4.0
6     5.0
7     5.0
8     4.0
9     3.0
10    2.0
11    1.0
```

Comment: I actually have much more data, like around 4000, but i m just using a sample of it here. and i m hoping to have a much larger window size than just 10

Comment: this might just work though. Let me try it and get back to you. I ll just tweak the values in your code.

Comment: You should use `min_periods=1` in `rolling` to avoid the initial NaNs

Comment: oh thats a great idea! I was manually keeping track of indexes and if its smaller than my set window size, i use the index size instead.

Comment: yes, sure! gimme a minute. I was working on some other parts